# Non-english special characters in knitr

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, knitr

I am using knitr 1.1. in R 3.0.0 and within WinEdt (RWinEdt 2.0). I am having problems with knitr recognizing Swedish characters (ä, ö, å). This is not an issue with R; those characters are even recognized in file names, directory names, objects, etc. In Sweave it was not a problem either.

I already have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in my document, but knitr does not seem able to handle the special characters. After running knitr, I get the following message:

```
Warning in remind_sweave(if (in.file) input) :
It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax; you may need Sweave2knitr("deskriptiv 130409.Rnw") to convert it to knitr

processing file: deskriptiv 130409.Rnw

(*) NOTE: I saw chunk options "label=lÃ¤ser_in_data"
please go to http://yihui.name/knitr/options (it is likely that you forgot to 
quote "character" options)

Error in parse(text = str_c("alist(", quote_label(params), ")"), srcfile = NULL) : 
1:15: unexpected input
1: alist(label=lÃ¤
                 ^
Calls: knit ... parse_params -> withCallingHandlers -> eval -> parse
Execution halted
```

The particular label it complains about is label=läser. Changing the label is not enough, since knitr even complains if R objects use äåö.

I used Sweave2knitr() since the file originally was created for Sweave, but the result was not better: now all äåö have been transformed to Ã¤pÃ¥Ã¶, both in the R chunks and in the latex text, and knitr still gives an error message.

Session info:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252           LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.1
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.0
```

As I mentioned there are file names and objects with Swedish characters (since that has not been a problem before), and also the text needs to be in Swedish.

Thank you for any help in getting knitr to work outside of English.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to contact the maintainer of the [R-Sweave mode](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/R-Sweave.php) in WinEdt if you are using this mode to call `knitr`. The issue is WinEdt has to pass the encoding of the file to `knit()` if you are not using the native encoding of your OS. You mentioned `UTF-8` but that is not the native encoding for Windows, so you must not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unless you are sure your file is UTF8-encoded.

There are several problems mixed up here, and it is unlikely to solve them all with a single answer.

The first problem is `label=läser`, which really should be `label='läser'`, i.e. you [must quote](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) all the chunk labels (check other labels in the document as well); `knitr` tries to automatically quote your labels when you write `<<foo>>=` (it is turned to `<<'foo'>>=`), but this does not work when you use `<<label=foo>>=` (you have to write `<<label='foo'>>=` explicitly). But this problem is perhaps not essential here.

I think the real problem here is the file encoding (which is nasty under Windows). You seem to be using `UTF-8` under a system that does not respect `UTF-8` by default. In this case you have call `knit('yourfile.Rnw', encoding = 'UTF-8')`, i.e. pass the encoding to `knit()`. I do not use WinEdt, so I have no idea how to do that. You can [hard-code the encoding in the configurations](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/), but that is not recommended.

Two suggestions:

1. do not use `UTF-8` under Windows; use your system native encoding (`Windows-1252`, I guess) instead;
2. or use RStudio instead of WinEdt, which can pass the encoding to `knitr`;

BTW, since `Sweave2knitr()` was popped up, there must be other problems in your Rnw document. To diagnose the problem, there are two ways to go:

1. if you use `UTF-8`, run `Sweave2knitr('deskriptiv 130409.Rnw', encoding = 'UTF-8')`
2. if you use the native encoding of your OS, just run `Sweave2knitr('deskriptiv 130409.Rnw')`

Please read the [documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) if you have questions about the diagnostic information printed out by `Sweave2knitr()`.

Comment: Thanks. At least now I am able to run knitr() on my file but special characters still are a problem. I corrected the Sweave parts to comply to knitr(). The latex text runs correctly by specifying (in this order): <br/> '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}'
'\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}'.

Comment: @user2266041 If you are sure you are using UTF-8, the answer by Gilbert should work.

Answer (score 2):

R-Sweave invokes `knitr` through the `knitr.edt` macro, which itself uses the code in  `knitrSweave.R` to launch knit. The `knit`command in this later script is near the top and reads `res <- knit(filename)`.

Following Yihui's suggestion, you can try to replace this command with

```
res <- knit(filename, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

The `knitr.edt` and `knitrSweave.R` files should be in your `%b\Contrib\R-Sweave` folder, where `%b` is your winEdt user folder (something like `"C:\Users\userA\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 7"` under Win 7).

Currently, I do not know how we could pass the encoding as an argument to avoid this hard coding solution.

I would suggest to avoid extended characters in file names which can only be sources of problems. Personally, I never use such names.

Comment: Gilbert: Thanks for your answer. I added the text you mentioned but I still have problems with knitr accepting special characteres in the R chunks. Filenames and R objects containing äåö are simply not read.